# Harmony Search algorithm adapted to Travelling Salesman

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman

I'm searching for an adaptation of Harmony Search algorithm which resolved Travelling Salesman Problem. I must implement it and describe results. I found some solutions like:
http://www.academia.edu/6709329/Adaptation_of_the_Harmony_Search_Algorithm_to_solve_the_travelling_salesman_problem

http://www.jtacs.org/archive/2013/1/4/JTACS_2013_01_04.pdf

but these solutions are not good and return poor results. I can't use any combinations with other algorithms, it must be clear Harmony Search(but modifications are of course permitted).
I was also looking for it in "Music-Inspired Harmony Search Algorithm: Theory and Applications" book and i found a description here, but it is not enough.

I think I've tried everything. I will be thankfull for any sources/ideas/examples showing how to do that.

Comment: Given the negative research results, what makes you think that it is *possible* to use Harmony Search to return good results for the Travelling Salesman Problem?

Comment: Pdf from my second link is a comparision of several algorithms for TSP. HS gives pretty good results.

Comment: But you own words: "*these solutions are not good and return poor results*". Please explain, what's the real problem here?

Comment: I think that these descriptions are not full, very sketchy and clue is not described. I've implement algorithms from above links and I've got poor results, but authors of publications have good results.

Answer (score 4):

I am a researcher in the field of computer science. I have had doubts about the harmony search algorithm since I have seen it for the first time in a conference talk. It turned out that harmony search is a special case of evolution strategies, which were proposed in the 60s. It also turned out that you cannot trust the numbers reported in harmony search papers, especially by the "inventor" of that method. To me harmony search is a hoax method and the "inventor" of that method very likely conducted academic fraud.

In short: If the algorithm does not work for you, it is very likely not your fault.

Sources:

1) [The Harmony Search Algorithm – My personal experience with this “novel” metaheuristic](http://www.dennisweyland.net/blog/?p=12)

2) A rigorous analysis of the harmony search algorithm: how the research community can be misled by a "novel" methodology (journal article published in 2010)

3) A critical analysis of the harmony search algorithm - How not to solve sudoku (journal article published in 2015)

4) [Neat Algorithms - Harmony Search](http://harry.me/blog/2011/07/05/neat-algorithms-harmony-search/)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented Harmony Search for composite web service selection. So i will try to create the whole model.

Steps:-

> 1) Initialize the problem and algorithm parameters.

Objective function with decision variables. For *TSP* decision variables should be the `weight` of the shortest path. Other variables of the *Harmony Search* can be set according to the performance.

- harmony memory size (HMS), (number of sample solutions)
- harmony memory considering rate (HMCR)
- pitch adjusting rate (PAR)
- Termination criterion (maximum number of searches)

These variables have to be tested actually, by running the algorithm and taking results with different values, for the best performance.

> 2) Initialize the harmony memory.

In this Step, you have to fill the memory by creating harmonies(random solutions) and storing them so that it can be worked upon later.

> 3) Improvise a new harmony.

You have 2 options to create a new harmony(solution). Either select one from already created one, or create a new one randomly. This depends on the harmony memory considering rate (HMCR). Its a probability with which you can choose either of the ways mentioned above.

> 4) Update the harmony memory.

The newly created harmony(solution) has to be compared with the already existing ones. If the new harmony(solution) is better then the worst harmony already present(total weight of the path of those solutions is compared in this), then the new harmony is saved in place of the worst one.

> 5) Repeat steps 3 and 4 until satisfying termination criterion.

Check if termination condition is met. This termination condition can be the number of iterations, or if a certain degree of accuracy is met.

---

Hope this solution helps.

Comment: Hi haris, I know how Harmony Search works, I've implemented one, but the classical HS returns unsatisfying results. Harmony improves very slowly. It must be a better way to choose cities for new harmony, I've tried getting the nearest neighbours, but it caused that algorithm gets local optimum with poor result. There must be another way to get better harmonies. Adaptations for other problems are modifications of classic HS and must be a good one form TSP. Sorry form my English.